# Who is able to edit http://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-faq

The last paragraph starts with a typo:

> Aside form reviewing suggested edits

should read

> Aside from reviewing suggested edits

The second word is spelled "**f `o r`m** " should be "**f `r o`m**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A correction will go out with the next build, thanks!